# Image and text lineup

Tags: html

I have a very simple question that I am sure will be very easy for someone to help me out with. I have a website that isn't lining up my image to text the way I want it to. If you scroll down the webpage about a little more than half way down you will see a logo image of a money back guarantee and text about the guarantee. My issue is right now the image does not line up right next to the text instead is currently just above the text. I have tried to recreate the table and pop in the image and text again however it continues to come up wonky. Any HELP would be much appreciated. Also if you have time please help me with the section "What experts are featured in the film?" the images look good however the names and info about the people directly below do not match up or look good. I can not fix spacing to make it all fit and look well together. PLEASE HELP!!! Thank you !!!

*Below is the url link

http://thetappingsolution.com/eft-tapping-film-Jesse.php

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You image and text located in different tags

```
<td></td>
```

You should cut you image from it's tag and paste it into tag with text

Answer (score 0):

The css of your second cell is set as

> vertical-align: baseline;

, when it needs to be

> vertical-align: top;